# Given two ranges [a,b), [c,d), check if they intersect

Tags: algorithm

The Google phone interview question I found from cscareerquestions was

> Given two ranges [a,b), [c,d), check if they intersect.

http://www.reddit.com/r/cscareerquestions/comments/2xrzst/just_got_rejected_from_google_after_my_phone/

The interviewee said:

> I just worked out the midpoints and the radii of the two ranges. Then checked if the difference in the midpoints were smaller than the radii summed.
>
> The interviewer mentioned two things. When taking the difference, what if one is smaller than the other. I said, just check and make sure you do it the right way round. About 10 minutes after the call, I realised I could've just used the absolute value of the difference instead. Then he mentioned that the [) notation means inclusive, so you don't include the last value. So I just decremented the end of each range.

What is a good way to do this problem? Would someone explain using examples?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the textbook answer:

If two ranges don't intersect, one of them is entirely to the left of the other one, which is to say: *b*≤*c* **or** *d*≤*a*. The comparison is ≤ because the ranges are half-open; if *b*=*c*, for example, the ranges don't intersect because *b* is not in [*a*,*b*).

So the ranges intersect if the above is not true:

**not** (*b*≤*c* **or** *d*≤*a*) ≡ **not** *b*≤*c*  **and** **not** *d*≤*a* ≡ *b*>*c* **and** *d*>*a*

---

Now, what about real-life programming? Aside from the above, there is one other case where two ranges do not intersect: when one or both of them are empty.

That's important because empty ranges tend to show up, and they may have arbitrary endpoints. You certainly wouldn't want to report that [0,2) and [1,1) intersected, because they don't, and that could be an important bug.

So let's ask a different question: what is the intersection of two ranges? And the answer is pretty simple: the left-hand edge of the intersection is the greater of the left-hand edges of the two ranges, and the right-hand edge is the lesser of the right-hand edges. Mathematically:

**[***a*,*b***)** ∩ **[***c*,*d***)** ≡ **[** **max**(*a*,*c*),**min**(*b*,*d*) **)**

Since a half-open range is empty if its right-hand edge is less than or equal to its left-hand edge, we can produce the more resilient definition:

**Ranges Intersect** **[***a*,*b***)**, **[***c*,*d***)** ≡ **min**(*b*,*d*) > **max**(*a*,*c*)

Comment: good answer, although a bit cryptic, but imagining two line segments with closed and open dots helped me see that your solution is correct.